# Asp.Net Webform export to excel is not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, internet-explorer, webforms

Here is the problem: I have a report which is generated with some repeaters and the resulting HTML is OK. After generating the report I call a function to export to excel:

```
protected void ExportToExcel(Control control)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Relatorio.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    control.RenderControl(hw);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

The problem: this function is working when accessing the report with Firefox, for example, but in Internet Explorer it doesn't. When putting a breakpoint at line Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString()); and when debugging sw.ToString() I find that it is empty.

I use this very same function to export some other reports and it works in Internet Explorer, in this specific report it doesn't. I've been trying to find HTML errors, such as missing closing tags, but I didn't find any so far.

Have you guys been through this situation? Do you have any tips on what to look for in my code?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The code you have posted is not going to perform differently between browsers, the problem probably lies else where in code that runs before this method is called.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you write to a stringbuilder and then call the stringbuilder.tostring()

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
control.RenderControl(hw);
Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I checked all the html, removed update panel and even so the excel export was not working. What solved the issue for me was passing a Placeholder to the function instead of a Repeater.

I still don't understand the exact reason why passing a Placeholder works and passing a Repeater doesn't, but the problem is solved.

Thanks for the replies!